# Vue Bootstrap - How to use double quotes in v-b-tooltip

Tags: vue.js

I am using this vue bootstrap tooltip. https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/tooltip

Now, I have this tooltip:

```
<label>Encoding
<feather-icon
    icon="AlertCircleIcon"
    class="mr-50 my-icon"
    v-b-tooltip.hover.right="'The encoding used inside the feed. Leave Automatically if you are uncertain'"
/>
</label>
```

On this toolitp text, I want to add **double quotes** around this word **Automatically**

If I use double quotes Its not render. Can you tell me how can I use double quootes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try assigning the sentence that needs double quotes in a variable and assign that to v-b-tooltip.

```
<template>
    <label>Encoding
        <feather-icon
        icon="AlertCircleIcon"
        class="mr-50 my-icon"
        v-b-tooltip.hover.right="tooltipText"/>
    </label>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data(){
    return{
        tooltipText:'The encoding used inside the feed. Leave "Automatically" if you are uncertain'
    }
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this-

```
<feather-icon
  icon="AlertCircleIcon"
  class="mr-50 my-icon"
  v-b-tooltip.hover.html="tipMethod"
/>
```

```
methods: {
  tipMethod() {
    return 'The encoding used inside the feed. Leave "Automatically" if you are uncertain'
  }
}
```